# "You could do worse than [x]"

Tags: phrases, idioms, rhetoric

I can't really tell what someone means when he says "you could do worse than [x]." [Live example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058247/successor-of-msxsl-exe):

> If you are just interested in a simple command line processor which uses MSXML 6 then you could do worse than using a simple JScript application.

Does anyone know what, exactly, he is trying to say? What nuance is he trying to convey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an example of *litotes*, which is stating a positive through a negative. It just means that [X] is not bad, that there are many alternatives that are worse.

In the sentence you link to

> If you are just interested in a simple command line processor which uses MSXML 6 then you could do worse than using a simple JScript application.

the person who responded is suggesting that using a simple JScript application is a good choice.

Comment: +1, few more examples for litotes http://www.uky.edu/AS/Classics/rhetoric.html#26, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes, http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/L/litotes.htm

Comment: I'd argue that they are not saying it's a *good* choice; they're saying it's not a *bad* choice.

Comment: @Kit: That is virtually the definition of *litotes*.

Comment: Reminds me of a Richard Dawkins quote, "You could do worse if you needed a theologian. Although I can't imagine anyone actually needing a theologian."

Answer (score 2):

It's a indirect compliment. You can go check out this link => http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic24532.html for more explanations.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite term for this sort of left-handed compliment (technically called a *[litotes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/litotes)*, as @Robusto pointed out) is "**[praising with faint damns](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,924489,00.html)**", a humorous inversion of the better-known "**[damn with faint praise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damn_with_faint_praise)**" (which is so old that [Alexander Pope is said to have stolen it from Wycherley](http://books.google.com/books?id=OnlWTPu62_wC&pg=PA286&dq=%22damn%20with%20faint%20praise%22&hl=en&ei=aHnxTerFFoH0tgOJ1bW1Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22damn%20with%20faint%20praise%22&f=false).)

Answer (score 2):

Another example of litotes is the cliché you've seen many times: "x is no small thing!" as in "to move the earth, no matter the lever, is no small thing."