# What is this type of idiom called: "I know he's not the smartest person in the world, but..."

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, idioms

Basically, when someone says something along the lines of

> "I know he's not the smartest person in the world, but he should at least pass first grade math."

It's peculiar because they are using a form of hyperbole to say they are not the smartest person in the world, but what they are really implying is that they are not smart at all.

**Edit**
This post was flagged a possible duplicate, I just wanted to clarify that what I am asking is not the nuance or meaning of the phrase, but the term for the idiom itself.  I do not believe this specific question has been asked.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case maybe you would prefer "He's not the sharpest knife in the drawer". Less of a hyperbole very similar meaning.

Comment: There are various idioms similar to the one DRF suggested. "He's not the brightest bulb" and "He's not the brightest crayon in the box" are pretty common. There's also the "He's a few _____ short of a _____" construction: for example, "He's a few cards short of a full deck."

Comment: If you're into Lit Crit terminology, it's ***litotes***. If you're an ordinary native speaker, it's ***understatement***. I'm both, so my choice of term would depend on who I'm talking to.

Comment: It's a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf); specifically, a member of the open "minimal degree" class  (e.g, _He didn't drink a drop/say a word/know a thing, not the sharpest pencil in the box, not the simplest idea to understand_, etc.)

Comment: @Nicole: You missed _'He's not the sharpest tool in the shed'_

Comment: possible duplicate of ["You could do worse than \[x\]"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/you-could-do-worse-than-x)

Comment: In the Southern USA, we would add ", bless his heart" between "world" and ", but", or at the beginning of the sentence: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/164459/49890

Comment: I'm a little confused because your example depends on the context. The speaker could be talking to someone who's underestimating the prospective student and clarifying that although he's not particularly smart, he's not particularly dumb, either. I don't think the speaker is necessarily implying that "[the prospective student is] not smart at all."

Comment: @Nicole, that's reminded me of my favourite: "He's three coupons short of a toaster."

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's called [***litotes***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).

From Wikipedia:

> In rhetoric, **litotes** is a figure of speech wherein **understatement is used to emphasize a point by stating a negative to further affirm a positive**, often incorporating double negatives for effect
>
> For example, "She's not bad looking" could be used to express that someone is gorgeous. Or it could convey that she's not particularly ugly, but also isn't particularly attractive.
>
> **The degree of emphasis depends on the context in which it is used.**

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/litotes):

> **litotes**: <sub><sup>**[MASS NOUN]**</sup></sub> Ironical understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of its contrary (e.g. I shan’t be sorry for I shall be glad).

Comment: I'd rate "She's not bad looking" below "She's good looking", and certainly not as high as "She's gorgeous".

Comment: @Sankarane - unless it's also a form of sarcasm where you might say about someone who is stunning, "Eh! She's not bad looking!"

Comment: @Sankarane: From Wikiedia: The degree of emphasis depends on the context in which it is used. So, it's aplicable in both the cases.

Comment: @Tushar Raj: That's right, when there's sarcasm, as Kristina points out.

Comment: Wow, awesome answer. Never heard of this one before.

Comment: There's a huge difference between _Eh, she's not that bad looking_ and _Wow! Not bad!_

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a "euphemism", a figure of speech where you substitute a milder word or phrase for one considered to be too harsh or offensive. ("you know, **he isn't the smartest person in the world**" instead of "**he is dumb**".

> - A [euphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) is a generally innocuous word or expression used in place of one that may be found offensive or suggest something unpleasant. Some euphemisms are intended to amuse; while others use bland, inoffensive terms for things the user wishes to downplay. Euphemisms are used to refer to taboo topics (such as disability, sex, excretion, and death) in a polite way, or to mask profanity.
> - euphemism - "a mild or pleasant word or phrase that is used instead of one that is unpleasant or offensive" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism)

examples of euphemisms:

- *to pass away* instead *to die*
- *ethnic cleansing* instead of *genocide*
- *pregnancy termination* instead of *abortion*
- *adult entertainment* instead of *pornography*
- *go all the way* instead of *have sex*
- *enhanced interrogation methods* instead of *torture*
- *undocumented workers* (when they are working for you) instead of *illegal aliens* (when they are not)

Comment: I'd hardly call it "euphemistic" to tell someone they're *not the sharpest tool in the box*, or similar. ***Biting sarcasm***, more like.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **IMHO**, to say that someone "isn't the smartest person in the world", is a euphemism. Not a set phrase like the examples I cited, I agree.

Comment: Actually, it's only when your ping made me come back to this one that I've realized many/most (all?) euphemistic usages are effectively a type of understatement. So although I stand by my first comment, I'm cancelling my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You might call that a [backhanded compliment](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:+backhanded+compliment):

> A backhanded compliment, also known as a left-handed compliment or asteism, is an insult that is disguised as a compliment. Sometimes, a backhanded compliment may be inadvertent. However, the term usually connotes an intent to belittle or condescend.

Comment: I thought it was a "left-handed compliment"...

Comment: @Oldbag Directly from the quoted definition: "A backhanded compliment, **also known as a left-handed compliment** or asteism..."

Comment: Thanks. I dunno, "backhanded" conjures violent images for me. Rather than, say, a tennis stroke, I see Al Pacino (as various characters) whappin' somebody across the face. "Left-handed" simply sounds a bit sneaky. (IMHO)

Comment: @Oldbag I don't know what to tell you- the definition of backhanded compliment is the same as the definition of left-handed compliment. You say potato; I say tomato.