# you could do worse than + -ing

Tags: verbs, idioms, gerund-vs-infinitive

Merriam-Webster defines "[could do worse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/could%20do%20worse)" as an idiom:

> used to say that a particular choice, action, etc., is not a bad one
> You *could do worse* than **to vote** for her.

Although I would have gone with simply "vote" without "to" myself, I think it's still okay to add "to" after "could do worse than", as shown in M-W.

That said, I was wondering if using "voting" would be also correct here.

There's [a 2011 thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29265/27275) showing this form:

> ...you could do worse than **using** a simple JScript application.

Where nobody seems to raise any question about the form "using."

And then here's [a 2022 New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/06/16/books/10-new-books-we-recommend-this-week.html) adopting the form "adding":

> There’s a character in Adam White’s debut novel, “The Midcoast,” who at one point starts to chafe against her small-town circumstances and decides to do something about it. “She went to the library,” White writes, “and started checking out every kind of book — romance novels, spy novels, biographies, memoirs, history books, cookbooks — anything in print.” That’s my kind of character, I thought when I reached that passage, and if it’s your kind of character too then you could do worse than **adding** “The Midcoast” (think “Ozark” meets “The Great Gatsby” in Maine) to your reading list this week.

Does this mean this -ing form is always natural after "could do worse than"?

Comment: 'You could do worse than marrying the King of England.' https://www.grunge.com/216607/the-tragic-final-days-of-henry-viiis-second-wife-anne-boleyn/

Comment: I think requesting a specific answer from a reputable source regarding the use of an idiomatic construction is inherently unreasonable; yes, "you could do worse than using a simple JScript application" parses grammatically to the meaning intended - which is what a formal source could tell you. It's an unusual use of the idiom, but idioms are by definition unusual uses of language. I don't know that you can have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @RyanJensen What makes you say it's an unusual use of the idiom? I don't think idioms are necessarily outside the realm of grammatical explanation. The idiom 'you can have your cake and eat it too' certainly follows all the relevant grammar rules.

Comment: I think it's an unusual use of the idiom because I'm a native speaker and have heard or read the idiom used that way (with an -ing) perhaps three times in my life, while I have heard the 'to ______' form hundreds or thousands of times. As I mentioned in my first comment, yes, the -ing form is grammatically valid. That doesn't make it standard, though. There being no formal body who determines idiom usage, I assumed standard or normal is what you meant when you asked if it would be 'correct.'

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries include sentences involving different strings after 'than':

> - [+ infinitive]: *He could do worse than marry Eleanor*. [[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-could-do-worse-than-do-something)]
> - [+ infinitive]: *You could do worse than take a leaf out of the health economists' book.* [[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-could-do-worse-than-do-something)]

> - [+ to-infinitive]: *The West could do worse than to base its policy towards the Middle East on that aspiration.*
>   [[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-could-do-worse-than-do-something)]
> - [+ to-infinitive]: *You could do worse than to vote for her.* [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/could%20do%20worse)]

> - [+ noun phrase]: *If you’re looking for a good career, you could do worse than a job in banking.*

[[Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+could+do+worse)]

I've found no authority licensing the use of an ing-clause after 'could do worse than', but there are reasonable numbers of examples on the internet:

> - *And later, you could do worse than trying some traditional Dutch food for dinner.*
>   [[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/you+could+do+worse)]
> - *Politicians could do worse than going to see Sartre's play*. [[Jonathan Webber, New
>   Statesman](https://www.newstatesman.com/author/jonathan-webber)]
> - ... *role in today's complex world, you could do worse than seeing what Stanley McChrystal has to say about the subject*  . . . [[Michael
>   Herrera; MHA
>   Consulting](https://www.mha-it.com/2022/02/03/our-complex-world-demands-a-team-of-teams/)]
> - *In the wake of all the scandals and controversies, the Catholic Church could do worse than having a scientist as pope.* [[The Guardian;
>   2013](https://www.theguardian.com/science/brain-flapping/2013/feb/11/pope-resigns-scientist-applies-job)]

But this is partly subjective; I'd use *In the wake of all the scandals and controversies, the Catholic Church could do worse than to have a scientist as pope.*

I'd say that there is a style rather than a grammatical constraint on the optimal choices here.

- *If you’re looking for a good career, you could do worse than a job in banking* is punchier than an alternative phrasing using say 'getting / ...'.
- *He could do worse than marry Eleanor* sounds less stuffy than *He could do worse than to marry Eleanor*.
- *The West could do worse than to base its policy towards the Middle East on that aspiration* is easier to parse than *The West could do worse than base its policy towards the Middle East on that aspiration* and the formal tone is not out of place.
- *Politicians could do worse than going to see Sartre's play* sounds more natural than *Politicians could do worse than go to see Sartre's play*  or *Politicians could do worse than to go to see Sartre's play* (the 'go to see' structure informs here).

Comment: What do you think licenses the VPs following _could do worse than_? In the OP, the VPs are _to vote for her_, _using a simple JScript application_, and _adding “The Midcoast” to your reading list this week_. I doubt that the VPs are comparative clauses even though they follow "than". If we can figure out the thing that licenses the VPs, we might be able to figure out whether the -ing form is also grammatical.

Comment: In a similar construction, do you think it's still better to use -ing than (to)-infinitive? _Politicians could do more than going to see Sartre's play_

Comment: C1: The stuff of theses. And _then_ someone writes a conflicting one. C2: I think I'm with you in thinking that 'could do more than go' or 'could do more than just go' sounds better than 'could do more than going'. What a language.

Comment: C1: I think it should be either _than_ or the matrix clause that licenses the complement of _than_. Does it have to be that difficult to figure out?

Comment: It's usage, not traditional rules, that license. Hence 'extragrammatical idioms' (and the others; why not 'boat of the desert' / 'kick the pail' / 'Hold your mules! / 'Tom's your uncle / ...?) My opinion is that " 'Politicians could do worse than going to see Sartre's play' sounds more natural than 'Politicians could do worse than go to see Sartre's play' or 'Politicians could do worse than to go to see Sartre's play' ... but others could well disagree. At some levels, idiomaticity is as important as grammaticality.

Comment: C2: Is the difference attributable to the fact that "more" is the object of "do" whereas "worse" isn't?

Comment: I'd not analyse 'do more than' other than as a unit. If you go that way, 'more than go' has surely to be seen as the object, hasn't it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean you'd analyze _do more than_ as a unit in _Politicians could do more than go to see Sartre's play_? I said the object of _do_ is _more_. I didn't say it's _more than go_ or _more than go to see Sartre's play_.

Comment: 'Do more than' = 'exceed' is an obvious synonym for one usage, and Crystal argues for lexemes as units of meaning. With 'do more than pay lip service', admittedly there's probably no single-word close synonym, but '[could] do more than paying lip service' can be rendered '[could] better/surpass paying lip service'. [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/improve-on#:~:text=improve%20on-,phrasal%20verb,improved%20on%20last%20year's%20figures.) classes 'improve on' as a lexeme ('phrasal verb').

Answer (score 0):

The essence here is that whatever follows "you could do worse than" (in the given context) has to function as a noun phrase/substantive of some sort that will provide a comparator.

The full infinitive; the bare infinitive, and a gerund all fulfil that criterion as do other substantive phrases.

You could do worse than **a horse**.

You could do worse than **buy a horse**.

You could do worse than **to buy a horse.**

You could do worse than **buying a horse**.

You could do worse than **the buying of a horse**.

You could do worse than **that**.

You could do worse than **John**.

You could do worse than **John's**.

You could do worse than **his**.

You could do worse than **him**.

You could do worse than **the one that John brought on Saturday when he was drunk**.